# How can I display MySQL profiling data for a Rails migration?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-migration

How do I get a dump of the SQL that my rails migration is attempting to execute?

I've tried using [mysql profiler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html)

MySQL Console: `set profiling=1;`

Rails Console: 
     `require 'path/to/my_data_migration.rb'
     MyDataMigration.down`

MySQL Console: `show profiles;`
This returns me back:  `Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Environment: Rails 3.2.17

DB: MySQL 5.5.28

If this functionality isn't baked into ruby/rails/mysql I'd be interested in learning about a tools that can dump the profiled SQL to the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one answer [here](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/displaying-mysql-query-line) from DZone snippets.

In rails console:

     `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
     ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!`

One thing that makes this not the most ideal answer is that if you need to do a hard reload of the rails console (not `reload!`), then you will have to punch these lines in again.  It would be nice if there was a way to keep the profiling running in a background process.